# How to call method from another class without passing context?

Tags: android, android-context

I am currently trying to call a method from a utility class that will reference a new cursor created for this utility method.  Unfortunately, my new class will not let me create the cursor without context.  I have tried numerous ways of passing context from the calling activity, but get null pointer exceptions in most cases.

Here is the portion of my code:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Tools.pickRandomItem();

                    }
});
```

and in the Tools Class:

```
     public static void pickRandomItem() {   

    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, 
               null, null,MediaColumns.TITLE + " ASC");




}
```

Using the above code it throws an error on `getContentResolver()`, and all attempts I've made to pass context have failed.

I am fairly new to programming for Android, and don't fully understand the concept of contexts. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Even though this question is older, better discussion and clearer answers are happening on this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666589/using-getresources-in-non-activity-class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a class that extends [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) for your project (you have to declare it in the Manifest too), in the Application make a

```
private static MyApplication app
```

in the onCreate() of it assign it to the field

```
app = this;
```

and make a

```
public static MyApplication get()
```

in it. When you need a Context you can use a

```
MyApplication.get()
```

Comment: I guess getApplicationContext() is another way of doing the same.

Comment: use getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 2):

A few hints on Context:

1. Get Context in you View via `getContext()` and pass it to `getContentResolver(context)`.
2. Use application-context approach as described here by @apps.
3. Don't store context inside Activity or Views. This leads to [memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Through your advice and more reading I have learned how critical context handling is to memory management.