# Unable to Create ArrayAdaptor from ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create an Array Adaptor from an ArrayList

```
 ArrayList<String> serverarray ;
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,serverarray);
```

But i keep getting this

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.FindServer, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined
```

What im i doing wrong?

Comment: have you initialized serverarray ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,serverarray);
```

`this` in your current context is `MainActivity.FindServer` which is not a valid `Context` object i believe.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you are trying to invoke is of signature:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

The 2nd and third 3rd arguments seem okay, so probably `this` as a first argument is not of type `Context`.

You need to pass a reference to the context of `MainActivity` in your `MainActivity.FindServer` class, and then pass that as your first argument.

I'd suggest having a look here: [How to retrieve a context from a non-activity class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867084/how-to-retrieve-a-context-from-a-non-activity-class)

Comment: Thanks ... there was an answer posted already...anyway i have upvoted your answer.