# Nullpointer exception on mediaplayer on a different class

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-context

I ahve a problem with this app. 
I think it's a matter of context , but I can not identify the problem and then solve it either ...
I already posted a question with unc ode similar , but a person in the comments ( the only one who commented told me to repost the question by adding more details ... The point is that I really have no other details! I could call this function from main, but because of this difficulty , I mAIN untidy , and would prefer to handle it in an orderly dividend all in different classes ..

```
package org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    /**
     * Created by Domenico on 03/08/2015.
     */

    public class actionview extends Activity {
        public boolean[] isplaying = {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false};
        public boolean[] ditofound = {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false};
        public int[] numerazioniastiera = new int[8];
        public boolean generalplay = false;
        boolean ditoscreen = false;
        public int action;
        int x;
        int y;


            public void getSound(String nota){
                Main Main = new Main();
                //Se la nota è docentrale
                Resources res = this.getResources();
                int soundId = res.getIdentifier(nota, "raw", this.getPackageName());
                MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,soundId);
            }

    }
```

The calling of method:

```
public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    actionview actionview = new actionview();

    onTouchEvent(event);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.nota1:
            System.err.println("Nota1");
            actionview.getSound("c3");
            //do stuff for button 1
            break;
        case R.id.nota2:
            System.err.println("Nota2");
            //do stuff for button
            break;
        case R.id.nota3:
            System.err.println("Nota3");
            //do stuff for button 1


       break;
    case R.id.nota4:
        System.err.println("Nota4");
        //do stuff for button 1
        break;
    case R.id.nota5:
        System.err.println("Nota5");
        //do stuff for button 1
        break;
    case R.id.nota6:
        System.err.println("Nota6");
        //do stuff for button 1
        break;
    case R.id.nota7:
        System.err.println("Nota7");


        //do stuff for button 1
            break;
        case R.id.nota8:
            System.err.println("Nota8");
            //do stuff for button 1
            break;

    }}
    return true;
}
```

}

Logcat:

```
  08-08 20:48:16.533    5056-5056/org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01 E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
08-08 20:48:16.534    5056-5056/org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01 E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-08 20:48:16.572    5056-5056/org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01 E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
            at org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01.actionview.getSound(actionview.java:27)
            at org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01.Main$MyTouchListener.onTouch(Main.java:97)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7701)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3982)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3475)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3444)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3551)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3608)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3475)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3444)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5610)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5581)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5710)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at c
08-08 20:48:16.579    5056-5056/org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-08 20:48:16.579    5056-5056/org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41694ba8)
08-08 20:48:16.583    5056-5056/org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01, PID: 5056
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
            at org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01.actionview.getSound(actionview.java:27)
            at org.altervista.xsparter.www.app01.Main$MyTouchListener.onTouch(Main.java:97)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7701)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3982)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3475)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3444)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3551)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3608)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3475)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3444)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5610)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5581)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5710)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android
```

Comment: Would this help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238588/how-to-call-getresources-from-a-class-which-has-no-context

Comment: use a Debugger in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem Add this to your onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
```