# java.lang.NullPointerException when referencing String in non Activity class, even when passing in Context

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I'd like to reference a String resource in my non Activity class by using

```
context.getString(R.string.E_mc2)
```

I know that this class has no context, and I know after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238588/how-to-call-getresources-from-a-class-which-has-no-context) that I have to pass in the context from  a class with a context using the constructor.  I made context a parameter in the non Activity class as seen in the below constructor and assigned it to a variable.

```
Context context;

    //constructor for class MyDataProvider
    public MyDataProvider(Context context){
        putInCommonMap();
        putInElectromagneticMap();
        this.context = context;
    }
```

I then try to create an instance in my Activity by using this to give it the context:

```
MyDataProvider dp = new MyDataProvider(this);
```

While it lets me run the program, I still get a NullPointerException when I try to include the string in my data. My logcat is below, if at all helpful:

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-16 11:14:48.160 2900-2900/com.gmd.referenceapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.gmd.referenceapplication, PID: 2900
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gmd.referenceapplication/com.gmd.referenceapplication.CommonConstants}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.gmd.referenceapplication.MyDataProvider.<init>(MyDataProvider.java:24)
                                                                                at com.gmd.referenceapplication.CommonConstants.onCreate(CommonConstants.java:37)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

I have researched this question and can't seem to find what I did wrong, and so I'd appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry all, Here is Common Constants:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.gmd.referenceapplication.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class CommonConstants extends AppCompatActivity {
    View view;


    //finds view and hashmap, passes to adapter to display
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_constants);


        MyDataProvider dp = new MyDataProvider(this);

        ExpandableListView view;
        view = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
        HashMap constantsHashMap;
        constantsHashMap = dp.getCommonMap();
        ArrayList constantsHashMapKeys = new ArrayList<String>(constantsHashMap.keySet());

        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, constantsHashMap, constantsHashMapKeys);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);


//creates toolbar
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    }



//manages app bar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow, menu);
    return true;
}




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.constants:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, FundamentalPhysicalConstants.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.joes_rules:
                //go to rules
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, ExampleListView.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.home:
                //Go back to the home screen
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.search:
                //open search
                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

}
```

Here is MyDataProvider:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Created by gmd on 6/13/2016.
 */

public class MyDataProvider {

    Context context;

    //constructor for class MyDataProvider
    public MyDataProvider(Context context1){
        context=context1;
        putInCommonMap();
        putInElectromagneticMap();

    }
    //strings for sub and superscript
    String test = context.getString(R.string.E_mc2);

    //data for common constants
    ListViewItem constant_common_data[] = new ListViewItem[]
            {
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Atomic Mass Constant", "1.660 539 040 e-27", "kg", "0.000 000 020 e-27"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Avogadro Constant", "6.022 140 857 e23"," mol^-1", "0.000 000 074 x e23"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Boltzmann Constant", "1.380 648 52 e-23", "K^-1", "0.000 000 79 e-23"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Conductance Quantum", "7.748 091 7310 e-5", "s","0.000 000 0018 e-5"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Electric Constant", "8.854 187 817... e-12", "F m^-1", "(exact)"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Electron mass", "9.109 383 56 e-31", "kg", "0.000 000 11 e-31"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Electron volt", "1.602 176 6208 e-19"," J", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Elementary charge ", "1.602 176 6208 e-19", "C", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Faraday constant ", "96 485.332 89 e-5", "C mol^-1", "0.000 59"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Fine-structure constant ", "7.297 352 5664 e-3", "  ", "0.000 000 0017 e-3"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Inverse fine-structure constant", "137.035 999 139", "  ", "0.000 000 031"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Magnetic constant", "4pi e-7 = 12.566 370 614... e-7"," N A^-2", "(exact)"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Magnetic Flux Quantum", "2.067 833 831 e-15", "Wb", "0.000 000 013 e-15"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Molar Gas constant", "8.314 4598", "J mol^-1 K^-1", "0.000 0048"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Newtonian constant of gravitation ", "6.674 08 e-11", "m^3 kg^-1 s^-2", "0.000 31 e-11"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Planck constant", "6.626 070 040 e-34", "J s", "0.000 000 081 e-34"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Planck constant over 2 pi", "1.054 571 800 e-34"," J s", "0.000 000 013 e-34"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Proton Mass", "1.672 621 898 e-27", "kg", "0.000 000 021 e-27"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Proton-Electron Mass Ratio", "1836.152 673 89", "  ", "0.000 000 17"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Rydberg constant", "10 973 731.568 508", "m^-1", "0.000 065"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Speed of Light in Vacuum", "299 792 458", "m s^-1", "(exact)"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Stefan-Boltzmann constant", "5.670 367 e-8", "Wm^-2 K^-4", "0.000 013 e-8"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr Radius", "0.529 177 210 67 e-10", "m", "0.000 000 000 12 e-10"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr Magneton ", "927.400 9994 e-26"," J T^-1", "0.000 0057 e-26"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Josephson constant", "483 597.8525 e9", "Hz V^-1", "0.0030 e9"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Von Klitzing constant", "25 812.807 4555", "Ohm", "0.000 0059"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Unified Atomic Mass Unit", "1.660 539 040 e-27"+ test , "kg", "0.000 000 020 e-27")
            };
    HashMap<String,ListViewItem> commonMap = new HashMap<String, ListViewItem>();

//data entry for electromagnetic constants
    ListViewItem constant_electromagnetic_data[] = new ListViewItem[]
            {
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr Magneton ", "927.400 9994 e-26"," J T^-1", "0.000 0057 e-26"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in (eV)/T", "5.788 381 8012 e-5", "(eV)/T", "0.000 000 0026 e-5"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in Hz/T", "13.996 245 042 e9"," Hz T^-1", "0.000 000 086 e9"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in inverse meters per tesla", "46.686 448 14", "m^-1 T^-1", "0.000 000 29"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in K/T", "0.671 714 05", "K T^-1","0.000 000 39"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Conductance Quantum", "7.748 091 7310 e-5", "s","0.000 000 0018 e-5"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Elementary charge ", "1.602 176 6208 e-19", "C", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Electron volt", "1.602 176 6208 e-19"," J", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Elementary charge ", "1.602 176 6208 e-19", "C", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "elementary charge over h", "2.417 989 262 e14", "A J^-1", "0.000 000 015 e14"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "inverse of conductance quantum", "12 906.403 7278", "Ohms", "0.000 0029"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Josephson constant", "483 597.8525 e9", "Hz V^-1", "0.0030 e9"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Magnetic Flux Quantum", "2.067 833 831 e-15", "Wb", "0.000 000 013 e-15"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton", "5.050 783 699 e-27", "J T^-1", "0.000 000 031 e-27"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in (eV)/T ", "3.152 451 2550 e-8", "(eV)/T", "0.000 000 0015 e-8"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in inverse meters per tesla", "2.542 623 432 e-2", "m^-1 T^-1", "0.000 000 016 e-2"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in K/T", "3.658 2690 e-4","K T^-1", "0.000 0021"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in MHz/T ", "7.622 593 285", "MHz T^-1", "0.000 000 047"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Von Klitzing constant", "25 812.807 4555", "Ohm", "0.000 0059")
            };

    HashMap<String,ListViewItem> electromagneticMap = new HashMap<String, ListViewItem>();


    //data entry for Atomic and nuclear constants :(
    ListViewItem constant_atomic_data[] = new ListViewItem[]
            {
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "alpha particle mass", "6.644 657 230 e-27"," kg", "0.000 000 082 e-27"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "alpha particle mass energy equivalent", "5.971 920 097 e-10", "J", "0.000 000 073 e-10"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "alpha particle mass energy equivalent in MeV ", "3727.379 378"," MeV", "0.000 023"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "alpha particle mass in u", "4.001 506 179 127", "u", "0.000 000 000 063"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "alpha particle molar mass", "4.001 506 179 127 e-3", "mol^-1","0.000 000 000 063 e-3"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "alpha particle-electron mass ratio", "7294.299 541 36", "(none)","0.000 000 24"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "alpha particle-proton mass ratio ", "3.972 599 689 07", "(none)", "0.000 000 000 36"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr Radius", "0.529 177 210 67 e-10", "m", "0.000 000 000 12 e-10"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "classical electron radius", "2.817 940 3227 e-15","m", "0.000 000 0019 e-15"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Compton wavelength", "2.426 310 2367 e-12", "m", "0.000 000 0011 e-12"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Compton wavelength over 2 pi", "386.159 267 64 e-15", "m", "0.000 000 18 e-15"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron g factor ", "0.857 438 2311", "(none)", "0.000 000 0048"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron magnetic moment ", "0.433 073 5040 e-26", "J T^-1", "0.000 000 0036 e-26"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron magnetic moment to Bohr magneton ratio ", "0.466 975 4554 e-3", "(none)", "0.000 000 0026 e-3"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron magnetic moment to nuclear magneton ratio", "0.857 438 2311", "(none)", "0.000 000 0048"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron mass ", "3.343 583 719 e-27", "kg", "0.000 000 041 e-27"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron mass energy equivalent ", "3.005 063 183 e-10", "J", "0.000 000 037 e-10"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron mass energy equivalent in MeV", " 1875.612 928","MeV", "0.000 012"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron mass in u", "2.013 553 212 745", "u", "0.000 000 000 040"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "deuteron molar mass", "2.013 553 212 745 e-3", "kg mol ^-1", "0.000 000 000 040 e-3"),

                    //resume data entry here
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr Magneton ", "927.400 9994 e-26"," J T^-1", "0.000 0057 e-26"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in (eV)/T", "5.788 381 8012 e-5", "(eV)/T", "0.000 000 0026 e-5"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in Hz/T", "13.996 245 042 e9"," Hz T^-1", "0.000 000 086 e9"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in inverse meters per tesla", "46.686 448 14", "m^-1 T^-1", "0.000 000 29"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Bohr magneton in K/T", "0.671 714 05", "K T^-1","0.000 000 39"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Conductance Quantum", "7.748 091 7310 e-5", "s","0.000 000 0018 e-5"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Elementary charge ", "1.602 176 6208 e-19", "C", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Electron volt", "1.602 176 6208 e-19"," J", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Elementary charge ", "1.602 176 6208 e-19", "C", "0.000 000 0098 e-19"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "elementary charge over h", "2.417 989 262 e14", "A J^-1", "0.000 000 015 e14"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "inverse of conductance quantum", "12 906.403 7278", "Ohms", "0.000 0029"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Josephson constant", "483 597.8525 e9", "Hz V^-1", "0.0030 e9"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Magnetic Flux Quantum", "2.067 833 831 e-15", "Wb", "0.000 000 013 e-15"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton", "5.050 783 699 e-27", "J T^-1", "0.000 000 031 e-27"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in (eV)/T ", "3.152 451 2550 e-8", "(eV)/T", "0.000 000 0015 e-8"),

                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in inverse meters per tesla", "2.542 623 432 e-2", "m^-1 T^-1", "0.000 000 016 e-2"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in K/T", "3.658 2690 e-4","K T^-1", "0.000 0021"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "nuclear magneton in MHz/T ", "7.622 593 285", "MHz T^-1", "0.000 000 047"),
                    new ListViewItem(R.drawable.star, "Von Klitzing constant", "25 812.807 4555", "Ohm", "0.000 0059")
            };

    HashMap<String,ListViewItem> AtomicMap = new HashMap<String, ListViewItem>();





//enters all data in common array into the common HashMap
    public void putInCommonMap(){
        for(ListViewItem i : constant_common_data) commonMap.put(i.getKey(),i);
    }

    public void putInElectromagneticMap(){
        for(ListViewItem i : constant_electromagnetic_data) electromagneticMap.put(i.getKey(),i);
    }
    //returns common hashmap
    public HashMap getCommonMap(){
        return commonMap;
    }


    //returns electromagnetic hashmap
    public HashMap getElectromagneticMap(){
        return electromagneticMap;
    }


}
```

Here is my Adapter I'm using:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by gmd on 6/13/2016.
 */
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String,ListViewItem> constantsHashMap;
    private List<String> constantList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, ListViewItem> hashMap, List<String> list){

        constantsHashMap = hashMap;
        this.context = context;
        this.constantList = list;

    }



    public View getChildView(int groupPosition,
                             int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
        String childTitle = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString();
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView childTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        childTextView.setText(childTitle);
        return convertView;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.constantList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return constantList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return constantsHashMap.get(this.constantList.get(groupPosition));
                }


    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String groupTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView parentTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewParent);
        parentTextView.setText(groupTitle);
        return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code block where `context.getString(R.string.E_mc2)` is executed.

Comment: Finally a Null Pointer Exception that isn't completely idiotic. This one gets me thinkin.

Comment: @Zircon I just added it, hope it helps

Comment: Post your method `CommonConstants.onCreate` please

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler of course, my apologies

Comment: I edited my answer, check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign your String after the context is assigned.

```
Context context;
String test;

public MyDataProvider(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    test = context.getString(R.string.E_mc2);
    putInCommonMap();
    putInElectromagneticMap();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, bu it does not seem to have changed anything

Comment: Post the code where getString is called then

Comment: Just added it, thanks

Comment: In which method is it called? Add more context please, I don't know if it is in the same class

Comment: This worked in the sense that I no longer have a NullPointerException but now the string just displays as the word "null".  Any suggestions?  Thank you so much even if not, I should be able to get this now.

Comment: Do you have the string `E_mc2` in your strings.xml file?

Comment: Yes and I also tried it with a different string just in case not sure what's happening

Comment: ok, please post other question with the information about it