# How can I use getResources from android

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I created a class MiOverlay that extends from Overlay.

And it doesn't recognize the getResources method.. What do I have to do. Here the full code of my class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;


public class MiOverlay extends Overlay {
    GeoPoint point;

    public MiOverlay(GeoPoint point)
    {
        super();
        this.point = point;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when){
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        Point scrnPoint = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(this.point, scrnPoint);
        Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        canvas.drawBitmap(marker, scrnPoint.x - marker.getWidth() / 2, scrnPoint.y - marker.getHeight() /2 , null);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think you need a context to reference resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with Luis Lavieri's answer. Your easiest solution would be to use the MapView's context:

```
Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapView.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Easy and no potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You are in an `Non-Activity Class`, so you must refer to what is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666589/using-getresources-in-non-activity-class) question. However, it is not recommended to pass the Context due to a possible memory leaking. Try to implement your resources within your `Activity` using `getResources()` or if you are using `Fragment`s, use `getActivity().getResources()...`

Anyway, your easiest option would be:

```
private Context context;
public MiOverlay(GeoPoint point, Context _context)
{
    super();
    this.point = point;
    context = _context;
}

@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when){
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    Point scrnPoint = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(this.point, scrnPoint);
    Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    canvas.drawBitmap(marker, scrnPoint.x - marker.getWidth() / 2, scrnPoint.y - marker.getHeight() /2 , null);
    return true;
}
```