# Android test : how to access application resource without context activity

Tags: android, testing, resources

I have a resource xml file in res/raw  named parameters.xml.
This file is used through a class called `Parameters`. 
The class `Parameters` uses Xpath to extract data from an xml file.

In the main activity I've coded this:

```
Parameters parameters = new
Parameters(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.parameters));
```

It works fine!

I want to test the `Parameters` class using the xml resource
without Activity ==> I do not have context anymore

At the moment, I've coded a main method inside `Parameters` class
(because I also use this class for other non android projects)

I've tried this:

1- `Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.parameter)` -
    does not work because my xml file is not a system resources

2- create an inner class (inside main method) which extends     `InstrumentationTestCase` - 
   does not work : exception runtime stub!

Any idea to fix my problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that without the context instance. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666589/using-getresources-in-non-activity-class).

Like someone pointed out it is best to get the resources inside of the Activity/Fragment and then pass it to the object, where you need it.

Comment: i understand but I do not want to use Activy/Fragment  to test my  class.

Comment: Then I would suggest to do what aloupas suggested, using the ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static reference for your application like this:

```
public class YourApplicationClass extends Application{

    private static YourApplicationClass instance;

    public YourApplicationClass (){
        instance = this;
    }

    public static YourApplicationClass getInstance(){
            return instance;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
YourApplicationClass .getInstance().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.parameters);
```

Add any point of your application will result getting the resources.

Also don't forget to add this inside application element in your manifest :

```
 android:name=".YourApplicationClass"
```

Comment: It's normally not a good idea to pass around Context objects in Android. It can lead to memory leaks. You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666589/using-getresources-in-non-activity-class)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using `Classloader` and

```
java -ea -classpath
```

to execute

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parameters parameters = new Parameters(ClassLoader.class.getClass().
    getResourceAsStream("/res/raw/parameters.xml"));
    ....
}
```

```
cd myprojectPath/app/src/main/java
javac Parameters.java
java -ea -classpath ".:../" Parameters
```