# "Cannot resolve method getResources" when trying to execute getResources in non-activity method using method widely advocated here

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to use getResources in a non-activity class.  I found some advice on how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666589/using-getresources-in-non-activity-class).  To use one of the suggested ways, by Lilzilala, (there are multiple, but mostly suggest the same thing), I have created a special class, used this to specify the resources as "res", and then instantiated this class using "new" in a line which invokes "getResources".

However, I'm getting a "cannot resolve method getResources" error on "getResources".  I'm a bit of a noob, but don't know why this is happening.  From what I can tell, this error happens when there simply isn't a resource with that name available.  Which makes me think maybe Resources doesn't contain getResources() by default?

```
class executeTrimmer<Resdefine> {


    public class ResDefine {
        private Resources res;

        public ResDefine(Resources res)
        {
            this.res = res;
        }}


 Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(new ResDefine(getResources()),
        R.drawable.bmpname);
}
```

EDIT - following suggestions that I add context, I have tried this:

```
class executeTrimmer<Resdefine> {


private static Context context;
public executeTrimmer(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

    public class ResDefine {
        private Resources res;

        public ResDefine(Resources res)
        {
            this.res = res;
        }}


 Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(new ResDefine(executeTrimmer.context.getResources),
        R.drawable.bmpname);
```

But this still brings up error "cannot resolve symbol getResources".  I've tried multiple different ways to pass context to it, and consistently faced the same error.

Comment: Use context from constructor and then use getresources like context.getresources

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar I thought the point of doing it this way was to avoid using context because it risks memory leaks?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Also @PrajwalWaingankar, how exactly would I do that?  Use context from constructor?

Comment: When u r calling this class from an activity then pass that activities context as a constructor argument of this class. Create a constructor of this class above  and then call that constructor in the activity from which u r calling this class and in that share the activity context.

Comment: Let me know if this works then will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getResources()), **"getResources"** is Context's method, therefore you can't call it out from nowhere, neither statically. This method requires a context instance.

In your case you must at least pass a context to your class to be able to invoke it as next:

```
context.getResources()
```

I think you got confused from seen it being directly called inside Activities without a prefixed context, but as all Activities are actually a context, this is why there is no prefix.

To clarify. When called inside an activity, this:

```
getResources()
```

is the same as this:

```
this.getResources()
```

where the prefix **"this."** refers to the activity, which in turn is a context by itself.

On the other hand your code should be like next, without the ResDefine class. And notice that the decodeResource call is required to be inside a method and not at class level scope (this is not allowed in Java). And in fact you don't even need to use a context, so pass instead the Resources instance from the caller's class which is supposed to hold the context:

```
public class executeTrimmer {

    private final Resources res;
    
    public executeTrimmer(final Resources res) {
        this.res= res;
    }
    
    public void loadBitmap()
        Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.res, R.drawable.bmpname);
        ........
    }
}
```

And for the caller, next a **very naive** example, so may get an idea:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
        new executeTrimmer(this.getResources()).loadBitmap();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and runs - thanks.  But what does it actually do?  How would I, say, use the output of this in a layout?